# IIS8, SSL Subdomains, SNI and single IP, and NopCommerce

Tags: ip, ssl-certificate, iis-8, nopcommerce, sni

We are using IIS8 and we are planning on hosting 2 secure sites on the same CMS (NopCommerce), as subdomains, on the same IIS instance.  We has some issues figuring out the right configuration figured out.  So I have a few questions about the configuration.

1. We are going to try to use a wild card SSL cert under (*.mydomain.com) to make sure the SSL should work.
2. Should the IP be specifically called out in the configuration or should 'All Unassigned' be the correct configuration the binding?
3. We tried checking SNI for one of the subdomains and both, but it killed the site and bogged down IIS.  Our assumption is to turn it off on both sites. Is this the correct assumption?
4. Nop question specifically, we entered both subdomains into the admin panel, but it asks for the HOST, but if we put 'domain.com' as the host, the first site in the list resolves but if you switch the order, the other site resolves and the first one doesn't.
   Should the HOST be the 'subdomain1.mydomain.com' and 'subdomain2.mydomain.com' ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard certificate for this.

1. Make sure your IIS Manager recognizes the certificate under "Server Certificates"
2. Make sure your site has a binding for HTTPS
3. Assign the certificate to the above binding
4. Configure your stores in nopCommerce

I tested the store configuration below and it worked with a wildcard certificate.

```
### Website Binding ###
Type: https
IP address: All Unassigned
Port: 443
Host name: 
SNI: unchecked
Certificate: my wildcard certificate

### Store 1 ###
Store URL: http://store1.mydomain.ch
SSL enabled: true
Secure URL: https://store1.mydomain.ch
Host values: store1.mydomain.ch

### Store 2 ###
Store URL: http://store2.mydomain.ch
SSL enabled: true
Secure URL: https://store2.mydomain.ch
Host values: store2.mydomain.ch
```

Comment: Thank you for responding and testing it.  We will give this a try.   We really appreciate it.

Comment: Also @Raphael, would separate IP addresses work with separate certs for each site in IIS and still use the same Nop application instance?  My assumption would be no because of they would be all the subdomains.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean. In my eyes, everything should work fine if you make multiple bindings with different certificates for one application instance. My test environment only has one IP, so i cannot test this case.